# looking for alternative rdbms for oracle which is build by russian

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle-database, db2

can anyone suggest any alternative to DB2, Sybase, and Oracle? I knew that Teradata is a good alternative to these. But most oracle guys ridicule to this they still think Oracle is superior and more robust to any other database that exists.

but I am looking for an alternative to Oracle, Sybase, SqlServer and DB2 which is built from scratch by Russian.

let me know what did I miss ?

Comment: Pretty much any RDBMS can replace those. What features are you looking for, exactly?

Comment: similar logical backup like RMAN offers, Seemless migration options like golden gate offers, DR replications eg. Datagurd offers,active-active clustering just like real application clusters offers and most precisely Automatic storage managers that AMS offers during disk sharing. @Alejandro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Linter SQL RDBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linter_SQL_RDBMS).

Keep in mind that **Yandex**, the Google of Russia, [passed from Oracle to PostgreSQL](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12489055) few years ago.

**Mao Tse Tung** once said:

> "I don't care if the cat is black or white, so long as it catches
> mice."

You shouldn't care if the software is built in USA, Japan, UK or Russia as long as it works.

If you think there might be a spyware in the software the reply is **YES!**

In all of them!

And also in all operative systems!

And there are even backdoors inside the [Hardware x86 CPUs](https://i.blackhat.com/us-18/Thu-August-9/us-18-Domas-God-Mode-Unlocked-Hardware-Backdoors-In-x86-CPUs-wp.pdf)!

There is no escape to that.

Comment: actually, oracle offers quite a smooth set of work after it's deployment eg. point-in-time recovery, RMAN as a logical backup, archivelog , in-memory-database and RAC (real application cluster and datagurd)  etc. so it comes to the customer as turnkey solution ie. all that a customer was looking for. in PG  or mysql you need hunt your meal to achive those features.

Comment: Yes but is not built by Russians. You were looking for a RDBMS built by Russia, right?

Comment: yes. I thought an alternative option must exist there also to compete.